# disjunctive syllogism in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am using swi-prolog. I want to model following statements in program.
*"Either a or b is criminal. b is not criminal."*

After modeling these statements. following query should work.

```
?-c(X).
 X=a.
```

But,
when I wrote above statements in prolog:

```
c(a);c(b).
not(c(b)).
```

this code does not compile and shows error:

```
No permission to modify static procedure `(;)/2'
```

How to model above two statements in prolog?

Answer (score 0):

afaik Prolog does not work this way. It tries to match your expression with all statements. So if you want to model "a is a criminal and b is not", then you can write

```
criminal(a).
not(criminal(b)).
```

but you can't say criminal(b) and in the next line not(criminal(b)), because this would lead to a contradiction.

the second line of my code ('not(criminal(b))') is actually redundant, because if Prolog doesn't find any matches of your term it will result in false, and backtrack for another solution. This means that you can simply omit all facts of not-criminals in this case.

you can then just ask Prolog which atoms it knows as criminals:

```
criminal(X).
```

and it will clearly tell you that

> X=a.

whereas b is not part of the solution.